# Send Email with Inline Image AND text in body

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using this code to send emails that include an inline image and some text (both fetched from a sheets tab). The script runs well but the debug is not clean. Could you please help me find a better syntax?

The error I get is:

> "Unexpected error while getting the method or property getBlob on
>   object DriveApp.File."

Thank you

```
function sendEmails() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('SendMail')
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();

  var quotaLeft = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
  //Logger.log(quotaLeft);

  if((lr-1) > quotaLeft) {
     Browser.msgBox("You have " + quotaLeft + " left and you're trying to send " + (lr-1) + " emails. Emails were not send.");
  } else {



    for (var i = 2;i<=lr;i++){


      var currentEmail = ss.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
      var currentSubject = ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
      var templateText = ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
      var currentname = ss.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
      var reply = ss.getRange(i, 5).getValue();

      var image = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getRange(i, 6).getValue()).getBlob();
      var message = templateText.replace("{name}",currentname);

      message += "<br/><br/><img src=\"cid:sampleImage\">";


      //Logger.log(currentEmail);

      MailApp.sendEmail({

        to: currentEmail,
        replyTo: reply,
        subject: currentSubject,
        htmlBody: message,
        inlineImages: {sampleImage: image},

      });

    } //close for loop

  } //close else statement

} //close sendEmails`
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means:

`No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it.`

Or in other words:

`ss.getRange(i, 6).getValue()` does not contain a valid file ID.

For debugging purposes add the following two logs before retrieving the image and observe the results:

```
...
Logger.log("Cell: " + ss.getRange(i, 6).getA1Notation());
Logger.log("Image: "+ DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getRange(i, 6).getValue()));
var image = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getRange(i, 6).getValue()).getBlob();
...
```

### How to make sure the cell containing the image ID is not empty?

Implement an `if` statement verifying if the cell is blank. If so, continue with the next loop iteration:

```
...
if(ss.getRange(i, 6).isBlank()){
  continue;
}
var image = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getRange(i, 6).getValue()).getBlob();
...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.It's very strange but now the code gives me this error:  SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (line 25, file "Code.gs") being line 25 the line wit Logger.log("image...)   I promise I copied and pasted the code precisely...any hint?

Comment: And it's also strange because the file ID that I'm attaching is under the same google account than the one running the script, so it has all the permissions to access the file. Besides, as I said before, the email is sent correctly, and the image is displayed in the body message, but it's a bit annoying to see this error...

Comment: Sorry there was a small typing mistake - a `:` instead of a `+`, I just modified it.  As to your second comment: You will see which line gives you the error if you implement the logs, but my guess is that you are looping through too many rows, so the last row(s) is empty and gives you the error. Without seeing your data - probably this error can be fixed by replacing `i<=lr` through `i<lr`

Comment: That is correct. I'm looping through some empty rows because sometimes I filter more emails and sometimes less in the sheet. If the error comes from this fact, then I will need to get used to it. Thanks

Comment: You can can make an `if` statement to check either the cell with the image id is empty before proceeding with the rest of your code.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please help me with the if statement? I'd like to run this same script even in cases where there are no attachment IDs in some cells. Thanks.

Comment: It is in my modified answer.

Comment: Thanks. I will implement this solution right away. Besides all this I was wondering if this script can be modified to accept a variable number of inline images per email, not just one, while keeping the possibility of no attachment too. For example, if the IDs would appear separated by a coma in the spreadsheet cell. Is there a way to implement this?

Comment: By the way, I tried the modified version of the script with the if statement isblank/continue  and it didn't work. The script gave no errors but the email was not sent... :(

Comment: the if statement isblank/continue sends an email only if the cell in column 6 is not empty, e.g. if there is an imageURL. If you did not get an email it means that the cell was empty. Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) to get a better understanding of the method.

Comment: If you have a new question, please create a new post specifying the question and showing your efforts to solve it as far as you can independently. Basically, if you want  to accept a variable number of inline images, you need to implement loops and conditional statements.